# Groovy string replace

Tags: regex, replace, groovy

I'm working on some Groovy code to take text that's meant to be a Tweet, and turn all hashtags into web-links to the Twitter hashtag.  In fact, I have that code working, but it fails when there's a bare `#` in the text that's meant to be read as a "number sign" instead of a hashtag.

The working (except for that edge case) code is:

```
static replaceHashTags(input) {
    while (input.contains(/#/)) {
        input = input.replaceAll(/(.*)#(\w+)(.*)/, { all, before, hashtag, after ->
            "${before}<a href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/${hashtag}'>${hashtag}</a>${after}"
        })
    }

    input.replaceAll(/<a href='https:\/\/twitter.com\/hashtag/, '#<a href=\'https://twitter.com/hashtag')
}
```

Instead of breaking what is mostly-working code before I had a solution, I wrote a test class to try out my new matching code.  It's failing, and I can't figure out why.  Here's the test class:

```
class StringTest {
    def checkContains(string, expression) {
        string.contains(expression)
    }

    @Test
    void shouldTestSomethingElse() {
        assert (checkContains('This is a string', /is/)) // Passes
        assert !(checkContains('This is a string', /werigjweior/)) // Passes

        assert (checkContains('#This tweet starts with a hashtag', /#This/)) // Passes
        assert (checkContains('#This tweet starts with a hashtag', /#(\w+)/)) // Fails.
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm not sure why that last `assert` fails.  What my expectation was going into this exercise was that I could simply replace `while (input.contains(/#/)) {` with `while (input.contains(/#(\w+)/)) {`...But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Are you sure `string.contains()` accepts regular expressions as argument? It doesn't look like it http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Hmmm.  Looks like you're right.  It doesn't.  So...1) I must be tired, and it's time to stop coding tonight.  2) I now don't really know why the first three asserts pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced `string.contains()` accepts regex as argument. This works for me:

```
def checkContains(string, expression) {
  string =~ expression
}

assert (checkContains('This is a string', /is/))
assert !(checkContains('This is a string', /werigjweior/))
assert (checkContains('#This tweet starts with a hashtag', /#This/))
assert (checkContains('#This tweet starts with a hashtag', /#(\w+)/))
```

Use `==~` to match the whole string.